# Reading duration of MP3 file from App script

Tags: google-apps-script, mp3

I have a MP3 file in google drive. Is there a way I can get duraton of that MP3 file using google app script?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html) page shows how to extract that information from an mp3 file by looking at the byte values.
So I wrote a short example and tested it. It seems to be working fine with all mp3 files I tried so far but there is no guarantee it will always work.
The getPlayTime function returns the play time in seconds.

```
function getPlayTime(file) {
  var bitratesV1 = [0, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256, 320],
      bitratesV2 = [0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56,  64,  80,  96, 112, 128, 144, 160];
  var bytes = file.getBlob().getBytes();
  for(var pos = 0;pos < bytes.length; pos++) {
    if(bytes[pos] === -1 && pos < bytes.length - 3 && (bytes[pos+1]&0xF0) === 0xF0) {
      var isMpegVersion2 = (bytes[pos+1]&8) !== 8,
          isLayer3 = (bytes[pos+1]&6) === 2,
          bitRate = ((bytes[pos+2]&0xF0) >>> 4)&0xF;
      if(!isLayer3) continue;
      if(isMpegVersion2) bitRate = bitratesV2[bitRate];
      else bitRate = bitratesV1[bitRate];
      var playTime = bytes.length*8/(1000 * bitRate);
      return playTime;
    }
  }
}

function test() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("music.mp3").next();
  var playTime = getPlayTime(file);
  Logger.log(playTime);
}
```

edit:
Here is a hopefully more accurate but also much slower version

```
function getRunTime(file) {
  var playTime = 0, numFrames = 0;
  var bitratesV1 = [0, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256, 320],
      bitratesV2 = [0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56,  64,  80,  96, 112, 128, 144, 160];
  var bytes = file.getBlob().getBytes();
  for(var pos = 0;pos < bytes.length; pos++) {
    if(bytes[pos] === -1 && pos < bytes.length - 3 && (bytes[pos+1]&0xF0) === 0xF0) {
      var isMpegVersion2 = (bytes[pos+1]&8) !== 8,
          isLayer3 = (bytes[pos+1]&6) === 2,
          bitRate = ((bytes[pos+2]&0xF0) >>> 4)&0xF;
      if(!isLayer3) continue;
      if(isMpegVersion2) bitRate = bitratesV2[bitRate];
      else bitRate = bitratesV1[bitRate];
      var pt = bytes.length*8/(1000 * bitRate);
      if(!isNaN(pt) && isFinite(pt)) {
        playTime += pt;
        numFrames++;
      }
    }
  }
  return playTime/numFrames;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this . I see the effort that has gone in. But unfortunately the duration is not accurate, it is very approximate. I uploaded audio of 24 second and it says 17 second. One with 24 minute and it says 19 minute. Any idea why ? Is it because of format?

Comment: If the mp3 file uses vbr instead of cbr encoding or if there are large images embedded in the file you will get inaccurate results. Improving that would require a lot more effort. Are you sure you require an accurate duration? And do you really have to determine that duration with apps script?

Comment: I tried to make it a bit more accurate but my new version is also a lot slower.